# Line type not working!

Tags: gnuplot

I've been having a problem with compiling gnuplot where it ignores what line type I put in and just assumes lt 1. Here's an example .sh file:

```
set term wxt enhanced "arial,16"     
set notitle   
set xlabel "x"  
set ylabel "y"  
set size square   
set xrange [450:750]  
set yrange [450:750]  
set key inside top right

set style line 1 lc rgb "#FF0055" lt 1  
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2C397D" lt 3

f(x) = x  
g(x) = x + 100

plot f(x) ls 2 lw 3 notitle, g(x) ls 1 lw 1 notitle

pause -1
```

This produces the following graphic: 
[image]

Anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is completely related to `gnuplot`, but has nothing to to with TeX/LaTeX etc -- it's off-topic, sorry

Comment: This is not a `.sh` file, it seems like it's a Gnuplot script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is **off topic**, but anyways:

In `Gnuplot 4.6` and earlier you have to use `set term wxt enhanced dashed "arial,16"`

But note, that `lt 1` is not a dashed line type, so maybe use lt 2 instead.

```
set term wxt enhanced dashed "arial,16"
set notitle
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set size square
set xrange [450:750]
set yrange [450:750]
set key inside top right

set style line 1 lc rgb "#FF0055" lt 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2C397D" lt 3

f(x) = x
g(x) = x + 100

plot f(x) ls 2 lw 3 notitle, g(x) ls 1 lw 1 notitle

pause -1
```

[image]

In Gnuplot 5 you can specify the `dashtype` of a line:

```
set term wxt enhanced "arial,16"
set notitle
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set size square
set xrange [450:750]
set yrange [450:750]
set key inside top right

set style line 1 lc rgb "#FF0055" lt 2 dashtype 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2C397D" lt 3 dashtype '..-'

f(x) = x
g(x) = x + 100

plot f(x) ls 2 lw 3 notitle, g(x) ls 1 lw 1 notitle

pause -1
```

See [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438219/how-to-produce-dashed-lines-in-gnuplot-5-using-tikz-terminal) for example.

Comment: This solution applies only to gnuplot version 4.6 and earlier.

Comment: @Christoph: You are right, thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think SE needs a place for gnuplot questions (for many users these naturally fit with latex).